# OpenCV and Python: Video output is empty if the source is not coming from the webcam

Tags: python, opencv, output, webcam, codec

I'm currently struggling with opencv in python 2.7

The aim of the program I'm trying to write is to open a source video with VideoCapture (is a mp4 with H264 codec), apply some filters (background removal, object tracking, stuff like that), display the result in a frame with imshow function, and save the result as another output video.

The output frame is shown as it should, but the problem is that the ***output saved*** **is** an **empty** .avi (or mp4, or whatever I put as argument of VideoWriter function). **Just a nutshell of few Bytes**.

So far you could just answer that I'm not using the appropriate combination of codec-format.
But **the odd thing is that** if I change the VideoCapture to stream **from webcam** (so just changing VideoCaputure("source.mp4") to VideoCapture(webcamindex) and leaving every settings as they are), **it works fine**!

My program is something like that, I just omitted the functions

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#VIDEO INPUT: SWITCHING THE TWO LINES BELOW IT WORKS!
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30, (640,480), True)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #A BACKGROUND REMOVAL FUNCTION
    maskedMotion = justMotion(frame)

    #A FUNCTION THAT FINDS CIRCLE THROUGH THE HOUGHCIRCLE FUNCTION
    circle = findBall(maskedMotion)    

    #DRAW THE CIRCLES
    if circle!=None and circle.size != 0:    
        for i in circle[0,:]:
            #draw the outer circle
            cv2.circle(maskedMotion,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
            #draw the center of the circle
            cv2.circle(maskedMotion,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

    out.write(maskedMotion)
    cv2.imshow('Result', maskedMotion)

    #ESCAPE SEQUENCE
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried setting the `fourcc` to `cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','P','4','V')` ?

Comment: yes, I tried. It keeps generate 5,6KB avi file or 258Bytes mp4 file. While regular one if the source is taken from the webcam (both the laptop built in and the USB one).

In any case (webcam good result or external source fail) openCV says:

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'mp4 / MP4 (MPEG-4 Part 14)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x00000020/' ???'

or

OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x5634504d/'MP4V' is not supported with codec id 13 and format 'avi / AVI (Audio Video Interleaved)'
OpenCV: FFMPEG: fallback to use tag 0x34504d46/'FMP4'

Comment: `cv` can be a pita sometimes, I'm afraid I cannot help you further. GL

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Comment: The reason could also be that the input video `source.mp4` doesn't have frames of size `640x480` as you are passing in the `cv2.VideoWriter`. Instead try reading one frame and pass that frame's size.

Comment: shawshank you are right! Thank you so much man!
If you repost it as an answer we can consider closed this topic and help someone else in the future! :)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by shawshank in a comment, the problem was the resolution. I was trying to save a video output with a smaller resolution than the original source. So I just changed

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30, (640,480), True)
```

for

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 30, (1920,1080), True)
```

Hope someone else will find this tip useful :D